# How to show 0 or null values if record is not found in reference table

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables
UserMaster , pagesMaster and pageRightMaster

UserMaster table stores the users data,
pagesMaster stores the pages data,
pageRightMaster stores the records of which user have what permissions.

here are table structure

[image]

Now i want to display all the pages from pages master table user wise with their permissions. If no permission record found for user for particular page, it should display as 0.

it means, if user selects the userid 2, then all the pages from pages_master table will be displayed along with it's page_permissions. If there is no record in page_permission table for particular user that means the user have no permission and it should display as 0.

Comment: `left join` is what you are looking for

Comment: Can you assist me with the query? It will be helpful

Comment: you can start with the query, and show us where you are stuck. From there we can help you. SO is not meant to write entire queries for anyone

Comment: From what I understand, you should start with a query on your `pages master`table and then start joining on the other tables. Start with that and show us where  you have a problem so we can help

Comment: *"Can you assist me with the query? It will be helpful"* Not when we're missing your query, no. if you show us your existing attempt, we can show you how to change it; but changing from an `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` may well be as simple as changing the word `INNER` to `LEFT` (depends on your `WHERE`).

Comment: select * from pages_mst u 
left join user_page_rights_mst up on u.id = up.fk_page_id 
left join  users on up.fk_userId = users.id where users.id=1



I have tried this but it is only giving me the records that are there in the table. Not that which are not there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEFT JOIN to display rows from "UserMaster", which is not in "pageRightMaster"
e.g.

```
select * from UserMaster u 
left join pageRightMaster up on u.id = up.fk_userId
```

You can add count+group by to display count of permission